# Javascript Regular Expression to Parse CSS

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, regex

I have CSS snippet like

```
.is-error{
  color: #d8000c;
}
.is-success{
  color: #4f8a10;
}
```

I want to parse it with regular expression in javascript such that i get an array, with class name and corresponding properties.

Regular Expression I wrote: `/^(?:([\w.\-\>\~\_\s\^\'\"\=\#\*\[\]\:\,\+]+)\{(.*)\})$/`

gives me output:

```
array[1] = .is-error
array[2] = color: #d8000c;}.is-success{color: #4f8a10
```

desired output:

```
array[1] = .is-error
array[2] = color: #d8000c;
array[3] = .is-success
array[4] = color: #d8000c;
```

Comment: can you show how you're storing the string?

Comment: There are already libraries for doing this; what is your use-case? If you are a beginner with regexes and not already a CSS expert, parsing arbitrary rules is not going to be easy. You'll also want to avoid using "one regex to rule them all"; split up parsing into different subtasks instead.

Comment: @beerbajay I was able to achieve what i wanted with the solution given by amit. I was experimenting parsing of CSS. I wanted to know how the CSS parsing libraries are actually working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to *match* it with a complex regex. But, instead *split* using a less complex one.

For splitting, we can use `String.split` and pass the regex `/[{}/` into it and then we use `Array.map` to trim the strings so as to get only the content and removing the white space.  But prior to doing that, we will just remove the unwanted empty strings using `Array.filter`

```
var arr = str.split(/[{}]/).filter(String).map(function(str){
    return str.trim(); 
});
```

It also has the advantage of working on all css-rules and not just classes, provided the CSS is a valid one.

Comment: Could you please guide me, if in my CSS file i have multi-line comments, then how could i work out such situation.
I can opt 2 options,
1) Retain all the comments at the same place.
2) Delete all the comments from CSS

For both of these, option how can i make it work